# How do I get the Happy Snap achievement on Android?

Tags: achievements, android, jetpack-joyride

I'm currently trying to complete all the achievements, but this one's giving me trouble because I don't get what it's telling me:

[image: Happy Snap: Save an action shot to your camera roll.]

How exactly do I save an "action shot" to my "camera roll"?

Comment: I don't think you *can* complete this on Android. It was only added very recently, even though iOS has had it for ages, and the button you would need to push to complete it on Android doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the *Android* version, you can't get this achievement, because the required button doesn't exist.

It was added in a fairly recent version, presumably by mistake - it was removed again in today's update, which seems to confirm that it should never have shown up on Android.

Comment: Sure enough, there was an update just now and the achievement is gone. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you finish a run, you'll see a random snapshot from it on the score screen. Click the snapshot to show it on the whole screen then click the Save button.

Comment: Save button...? Where's that? When I tap the snapshot, all I get is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4bNCo.jpg).

Comment: Very odd. On the iOS version (and Vita version IIRC) the button is on the bottom right. Is it posssible the Android UI is hiding that button? Could you flip the screen and check if different orientation changes anything?

Comment: That app doesn't flip for some reason. Anyway, as Michael said, there was an update earlier today which removed that achievement. Looks like it was never supposed to be on Android and I just caught a glimpse of it right before it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The game doesn't have it anymore but if you still want one I go into settings, go to customizable options, and turn on screenshots. Once thats activated, hold the recent apps key. Thats the one with the two boxes.